# On which date did the official name change of Lactobacillus sanfranciscensis change?

Tags: taxonomy, history, nomenclature

When did the change of official name from *Lactobacillus sanfrancisco* to *Lactobacillus sanfranciscensis* happen? An answer ((to the exact day OR within a few days) AND the name of the conference at which it happened) would be appreciated.

Comment: Most rule of nomenclature that I am aware of require that changes be made formally print and not at conferences.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Lactobacillus sanfranciscensis* first shows up in pubmed in [Gänzle et al. (1998)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC106434/). They reference [Trüper and De'Clari (1997)](http://ijs.sgmjournals.org/content/47/3/908.abstract) for the name *Lactobacillus sanfranciscensis*. The latter say:

> As none of them makes sense in the nominative apposition construction,
>   we hereby correct these names to forms that are in agreement with Rule
>   12c as follows.
>
> ...
>
> *Lactobacillus sanfrancisco* ("the city San Francisco") is corrected to *Lactobacillus sanfranciscensis* (adjective: "from San Francisco").

That issue of *Int J Syst Bacteriol* was published 1 July 1997, so I guess that's your date.

#### References

Gänzle M G, M Ehmann, and W P Hammes. 1998. Modeling of growth of *Lactobacillus sanfranciscensis* and *Candida milleri* in response to process parameters of sourdough fermentation. *Appl Environ Microbiol* 64(7):2616–2623.

Trüper H G, De'Clari L. 1997. Taxonomic note: necessary correction of specific epithets formed as substantives (nouns) "in apposition." *Int J Syst Bacteriol* 47:908–909.